# Store char variables in other char variables in C

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, declaration, c-strings

I am trying to do the following, create a multy-charr array with other char variables.

```
char data_info_1[] = "Wellcome.";
char data_info_2[] = "Please";
char data_info_3[] = "If";

int size_line= sizeof(data_info_1)/sizeof(data_info_1[0]);

char data_info[3][size_line]={{data_info_1},{data_info_2},{data_info_3}};
```

One solution would be the following one, but I am not interested in just putting the string right in the data_info variable

```
char data_info[3][size_line]={{"Wellcome"},{"Please"},{"If"}};
```

Could you please explain me why the first thing that I have writen is not valid. And if there is a solution to my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: `data_info_x` is a pointer, so you need an array of pointers.

Comment: @user3386109 `data_info_x` is an array, not a pointer. For the example posted above `sizeof data_info_1` yields `10` which does not look like the size of a pointer at all.

Comment: @pmg In the initializer `char data_info[3][size_line]={{data_info_1} ...`, `data_info_1` is a pointer, so `data_info` must  be an array of pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, neither of your solutions is correct, you can't initialize a 2D array of chars like that.

The second option would be valid if it wasn't a variable sized array, *i.e.*

```
char data_info[3][10]={"Wellcome", "Please" ,"If"};
                   ^
            Valid -> fixed size
```

---

Assignments like those would be possibe if you had an array of pointers:

```
char *data_info[] = {data_info_1, data_info_2, data_info_3}; //1
```

Or

```
const char *data_info[] = {"Wellcome", "Please", "If"}; //2
```

But these may not be what you need.

Option 1 will contain pointers to the original strings, any changes made to them through those pointers will be reflected in the original strings.

Option 2, the pointers are being initialized with string literals and those can't be changed, that's why I added the `const` qualifier as a metter of safety.

If neither of these constrains work for you, you'll need to copy the strings with something like `strcpy`, `strncpy` or better yet `memcpy`:

```
#include <string.h>
//...
memcpy(data_info[0], data_info_1, sizeof data_info_1);
memcpy(data_info[1], data_info_2, sizeof data_info_2);
memcpy(data_info[2], data_info_3, sizeof data_info_3);
```

Comment: If I decided to use the pointer solution that you proposed, should not the declaration be like: char *data_info[] = {&data_info_1, &data_info_2, &data_info_3};. Instead of char *data_info[] = {data_info_1, data_info_2, data_info_3};

Comment: @SergioPrieto, they are incompatible types, `&data_info_1` would a pointer to array i.e. `char (*)[10]` whereas each initializer is expected to be `char*`, a pointer to the beggining of the arrays. You could do `char *data_info[] = {&data_info_1[0], &data_info_2[0], &data_info_3[0]};` passing the address of the first element of each `char` array. If you passed a pointer to array, like you suggest, it would not be iterable `char` by `char`, but in blocks of 10 `chars` and would result in undefined behavior. If my explanation was not clear enough let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays may not be initialized by arrays. You may initialize a character array with string literals as you did in this declaration

```
char data_info[3][size_line]={{"Wellcome"},{"Please"},{"If"}};
```

Relative to your case you could declare an array of pointers to char like for example

```
char * data_info[] = { data_info_1, data_info2, data_info3 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

1. you do not need to divide by `sizeof char` becuse it is by definition `1`
2. You can only use constant expressions when defining or initializing global variables  `char data_info[3][sizeof(data_info_1)];`

To "store" one char array in other you need to copy it. Initialization will not work as you cannot assign the arrays.

```
#include <string.h>

char data_info_1[] = "Wellcome.";
char data_info_2[] = "Please";
char data_info_3[] = "If";

char data_info[3][sizeof(data_info_1)];

void foo(void)
{
    strcpy(data_info[0], data_info_1);
    strcpy(data_info[1], data_info_2);
    strcpy(data_info[2], data_info_3);
}
```

only structs or unions can be assigned. So you can wrap array into the struct and the assignment or initializations will copy the whole array.

```
struct stringWR
{
    char str[50];
};

struct stringWR data_info_1 = {"Wellcome."};
struct stringWR data_info_2 = {"Please"};
struct stringWR data_info_3 = {"If"};

struct stringWR data_info[3];


void foo(void)
{
    data_info[0] = data_info_1;
    data_info[1] = data_info_1;
    data_info[2] = data_info_1;
}

void bar(void)
{
    struct stringWR data_info[3] = {data_info_1, data_info_2, data_info_2};
}
```